# php, memcached, binary protocol

Tags: php, binary, memcached, igbinary

I'm trying to squeeze each bit from an application I'm writing, I've already installed and configured igbinary for serialization on apc, sessions etc.
I'd like to know if any of you have actual benchmarks with php and memcached using binary protocol. is it something valuable?

```
$memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_SERIALIZER, Memcached::SERIALIZER_IGBINARY);
$memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL,true);
```

thanks!

Comment: squeeze bits? did you compile your code (or parts of it) into a php extension? google "facebook compile php"

Comment: @ItayMoav Hi, I know about the php sorcery the guys at facebook made, so far I'm more than satisfied with APC, the app i run is stable on only two servers and it has an average of 72ms each request, so no need of hiphop php for now, I'm just looking for little details such as OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL for now. thanks though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe this will help you decide.

http://www.slideshare.net/tmaesaka/memcached-binary-protocol-in-a-nutshell-presentation